# Creating an EntityManagerFactory manually?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone know how to create an `EntityManagerFactory` manually? When I say manually I mean have it consume a special `persistence.xml` file?  This what I have tried and all has failed me.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
InputStream is = JPAUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/s-persistence.xml");
configuration.addInputStream(is);
_entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
      puType.persistenceName, configuration.getProperties());
```

`s-persistence.xml` looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="S_DATABASE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property value="false" name="hibernate.show_sql"/>
            <property value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" name="hibernate.dialect"/>
            <property value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" name="hibernate.connection.driver_class "/>
            <property value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:TEST" name="hibernate.connection.url"/>
            <property value="TESTOWNER" name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
            <property value="TEST" name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
            <property value="2" name="hibernate.connection.isolation"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I get the following error when running the java code.

```
ERROR   :: org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper|Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(2) Document     is invalid: no grammar found. 
ERROR   :: org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper|Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(2) Document root element "persistence", must match DOCTYPE root "null". 
org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid mapping
```

It's like it is looking for hibernate specific syntax in the `persistence.xml`.  I've also tried the EJB3Configuration.  It looks like my XML is well formed which is throwing me off as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: Were you ever able to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into the issue that

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
```

may not be reachable, so that validating the XML file against it can not work.

Try to not give the schema location like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I am still getting the same exact error even after making the change.  The top of my persistence.xml file now looks like what you suggested.